# If I apply decltype to an expresstion that yields an rvalue, do I always get a pointer? C++

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype, rvalue, lvalue

I know that if I apply `decltype` to `p`, where `p` is an `int*`, `decltype(*p)` is `int&`. And `decltype(&p)` is `int**`.

A reference being an rvalue, do I always get a pointer when applying `decltype` to an rvalue?

Comment: What do you mean by "a reference being an rvalue" ?

Comment: That the address-of operator yields an rvalue.

Comment: The address-of operator gives a pointer prvalue, not a reference ... and decltype of a pointer prvalue is indeed a pointer type, if that's what you are asking. decltype of prvalues that are not pointers, does not give a pointer type

Comment: A reference is not an rvalue. References have to do with *types*, and rvalues with *expressions*. I think you have a category error in your thinking.

Comment: Note also that "rvalue" isn't a value category, but rather a value category *group* consisting of the (actual) value categories xvalue and prvalue; `decltype` distinguishes those two.

Comment: @Ron: I'm actually stufying from C++ Primer at the moment and the question was asked as a means to try to understand the topic from the book. I've went trough the the previous chapters with no excessive trouble, but the Expresstions chapter hit me hard from the very fundamentals. Do you have any recommandations for well explained material on those online?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decltype` applied to...

- a prvalue expression gives a non-reference type,
- an xvalue expression gives an rvalue reference type, and
- an lvalue expression gives an lvalue reference type.

(There is an exception for id-expressions that I won't go into. Just consider "expression" to mean "any expression other than an id-expression" for the purpose of this answer.)

In all cases, the underlying type of the `decltype` type is the type of the expression.

To put this in code, let `U` be an object type. Then:

- With `U f();`, `decltype(f())` is `U`.
- With `U& f();`, `decltype(f())` is `U&`.
- With `U&& f();`, `decltype(f())` is `U&&`.

In your example, `*p` is an lvalue of type `int`, so `decltype(*p)` is `int&`, and `&p` is a prvalue of type `int**`, so `decltype(&p)` is `int**`.